# How to filter entities with nested arrays with CosmosDB

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an entity like this:

```
{
    "id": "xxxx",
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "name-01",
            "value": "value-01"
        }, {
            "name": "name-02",
            "value": "value-02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Our "questions" to data usually: Give me entities with attribute or attribute with particular value;

in SQL it was written like as:

```
select *
from c
where 
 and array_contains(c.attributes, { "name": "name-01", "value": "value-01" }, true)
 and array_contains(c.attributes, { "name": "name-02", "value": "value-02" }, true)
```

but I would like to extend a model to allow have suggestion of values in each attribute by transform an entity to:

```
{
    "id": "xxxx",
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "name_01",
            "value": "value-01",
            "suggestions": ["a", "b", "c"]
        }, {
            "name": "name_02",
            "value": "value-02",
            "suggestions": ["a", "d", "e"]
        }
    ]
}
```

With that structure I would like to ask: *Give me all entities that has specified attribute and value equals to "XYZ" or suggestions array contains "XYZ"*;

In general scenario if always add value into array of suggestions the ask would be "*Give me all entities that has specified attribute and suggestions contains XYZ*"

N.B. Also I would like to make queries : *Give me all entities that has more ALL specified attributes with constraints per each by suggestions*?

Please suggest how to write such queries or rebuild a structure of entities in Cosmos DB;

P.S. We can technically switch from SQL to other protocol to better make such queries;

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) along with [iterating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-object-array#Iteration) the attributes array.

Give me items with value "value-01" or suggestion "f":

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE(c)
FROM c JOIN attr IN c.attributes 
WHERE attr["value"] = "value-01" OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(attr.suggestions, "f")
```

Give me items with value "value-01" or both suggestions "a" and "f":

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE(c)
FROM c JOIN attr IN c.attributes 
WHERE attr["value"] = "value-01" OR
      ARRAY_CONTAINS(attr.suggestions, "a") AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(attr.suggestions, "f")
```